# How to pass custom flags to `bazel test` command

Tags: bazel, gflags

I have used [gflags](https://github.com/gflags/gflags) in my test to define custom flags. How can I pass such a flag to my test while running the test via `bazel test` command?

For example: I can run a test multiple times using:

```
bazel test //xyz:my_test --runs_per_test 10
```

In the same command I would like to pass a flag defined in `my_test` say `--use_xxx`, how do I do so?

Comment: I think the word flags might be overloaded. Do you mean arguments to the main method of your test runner?

Comment: it's interesting here because with `bazel run` you can leverage the fact that everything to the right of a lone `--` would get interpreted as arguments to pass down to the process while for build and run commands that blocked off section functions as [target patterns](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html) as in `bazel [<startup options>] <command> [<args>] -- [<target patterns>]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Use the `--test_arg` flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--test_arg).

```
bazel test //xyz:my_test --runs_per_test=10 --test_arg=--use_xxx --test_arg=--some_number=42
```

From the docs:

> `--test_arg arg`: Passes command-line options/flags/arguments to each test process. This
>   option can be used multiple times to pass several arguments, e.g.
>   `--test_arg=--logtostderr --test_arg=--v=3`.

You can also [specify arguments for the test as part of the BUILD definition](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common-attributes-tests):

```
cc_test(
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = [".."],
    deps = [".."],
    args = ["--use_xxx", "--some_number=42"],
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a main into your test. It will look like this.

```
TEST(A, FUNC) {
  // Your test here.
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, /*remove_flags=*/true);
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

It works fine for me.